# Why do I need to use " [[...]] " when using an if construct in a while loop with a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I couldn't get the result I wanted when I used `if[..]` in the if structure in bash script. I was told to use `if[[..]]` but the reason was not explained. What is the difference `if[..]` and `if[[..]]` ?

Example;

```
while true; do
...
...
...


            if [[ $warn = "error" ]]
            then
...
...
...
```

Comment: You don't _need_ them.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/118235)

Comment: @brkshn : It depends what functionality you need. After `if` can come any command - only the exit code matters.  I tend to use `[[` or `((`, because they are more flexible than `[`, but it's a matter of taste. But your question is misleading: You are talking about `if[` and `if[[`,  and both are nonsense. Correct would be `if [` or `if [[`. Be more careful with spacing, or it will bite you one day!